# Why does SuperTab output self when I press <tab>?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tags, code-completion, supertab

### The Setup

In my `.vimrc` I have the following lines:

```
" .vimrc
let g:virtualenv_directory="/Users/Kit/Development/virtualenv"
```

Then in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python/virtualenv.vim` I have these:

```
py << EOF
import os.path
import sys
import vim
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    sys.path.insert(0, project_base_dir)
    activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
    print "virtualenv in os.environ!"
EOF
VirtualEnvActivate my-virtualenv-python-2.7
```

In `~/.vim/ftplugin/python/virtualenv.vim` I have these SuperTab settings:

```
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
setlocal completeopt=menuone,longest,preview
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType="<c-x><c-]>"
```

In my working directory, where I always work from, I executed the following bash command to generate a `TAGS` file for all my `.py` files

```
find . -name '*.py' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 etags -l python
```

### The problem

For example, I have a `main.py` which has an object `app` inside it, such that the following script works fine:

```
import main
new_app = main.app() # works totally fine Python-wise
```

If, for example, I write some new code and try to use SuperTab omnicompletion:

```
import main
new_new_app = main.<Tab>
```

This is what I get:

```
new_new_app = mainself.
```

And if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times:

```
new_new_app = mainselfselfselfself.
```

### What works for me

If, however, I do the following:

```
new_new_app = main.a<Tab>
```

I get a whole list of `a..` objects that include those that don't belong to module `main`.

### What I want

If I set the following in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType="context"
```

Then, I use a module from the standard Python library:

```
import sys
sys.<Tab> # This will still result in sysselfselfself.
sys.p<Tab> # This will result in the correct list of `sys` members beginning with `p`
```

But the `"context"` setting won't work on my own modules:

```
new_new_app = main.a<Tab>
# Will say at the bottom: Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

## The Question

How should I set up omnicompletion and SuperTab so that it behaves for my own modules as for the standard library modules? As well as eliminate the `selfselfself.` annoyance?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think SuperTab does what other similar plugins do: they try to guess the context and call the correct builtin omni-completion to propose the most accurate results. Did you try omni-completion without SuperTab? `<C-x><C-o>`, `<C-x><C-]>`, `<C-x><C-u>` What is the outcome? Also what Pyton completetion script do you use?

Comment: @romainl, yes the key sequences you mentioned turn out all right. I think this is caused by a SnipMate bug. https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/issues/65

Comment: Try reverting to the original SnipMate.

Answer (score 5):

As you point out, this is caused by snipmate: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/issues/65

I also proposed a solution:
https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/pull/84

It did not get accepted, because snipmate should not be context sensitive.

There are two solutions for this:

1. Take my snipmate fork:

   https://github.com/davidhalter/vim-snipmate

   Which is probably not the best idea, since it's just my fork and I don't actively maintain it.
2. Fork https://github.com/honza/snipmate-snippets and remove the mapping for the dot (Using the dot will not be possible anymore, to complete self).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I just cloned your fork and also discovered all the cool work you and others have been doing on the new fork of Snipmate!  Excellent.